# Why just one of 5 threads pop elements from stack?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

```
public class ClassTest extends Thread{

    public static Object lock = new Object();
    
    public static LinkedList<Integer> stack;
    public SortedSet<Integer> set= new TreeSet<>();
    @Override
        public void run(){
            
            synchronized(lock){
                // try{
                    // this.wait();
                // }
                // catch(Exception e){
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                // }
                
                
                while(!stack.isEmpty()){
                    set.add(stack.pop());
                    
                    this.yield();
                    
                    // this.notifyAll();
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
        }
```

When i start() 5 Threads why just first one pop all elements and others do not pop anyone?
I tried to use wait() and notify() methods, but that didn't help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `yield` does not release locks. The very first thread that enters the synchronized block will keep other threads from entering until the stack is empty and the lock is released.

---

Here is an example that does what you want using `LinkedBlockingDeque`.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;


class Main {
    
    static final LinkedBlockingDeque<Integer> stack = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    
    
    static class Poller implements Runnable {
        final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Integer elem = stack.poll();
            while (elem != null) {
                set.add(elem);
                System.out.printf("%s: %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), elem);
                elem = stack.poll();
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            stack.push(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Thread(new Poller()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh yes, you're right.. Thanks.. So, what do you suggest to do, maybe some other way?

Comment: @DevJava First, I suggest to accept the answer, because it's the answer to your question. ;-) Then I suggest to not use `synchronized` here. You could use a data structures that is synchronized on the methods, e.g. `LinkedBlockingDeque`. Then all threads can call `poll` on it as long `poll` does not return `null`. Notice that you also need to use a synchronized data structure for `set`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. Sorry for bothering you, but is there any way to do this with synchronized block (maybe using wait() and notify() methods, or it is impossible.. Thanks again..

Comment: @DevJava I've just added an example with `LinkedBlockingDeque`. It's not as difficult as you might think. Yes there is a way doing that using `wait` and `notify` but it would be basically implementing a `synchronized` around every access on the stack. Do you know what I mean? It doesn't really make sense to use `wait`/`notify` here.